# C# regex how to exclude from string

Tags: c#, regex

Im working on regex on c#, and I need to get only a part from the string and exclude all the rest.

```
var file = "XD_ADX_W_CGX_CLAIMS_2021_07_11.TXT";
```

I want to only get "CGX_CLAIMS" from above string, XD_ADX is variable, *W* is static and 2021_07_11 is also variable

I was able to extract the date with the below regex:

```
 Regex r = new Regex(@"[_]\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}[.]", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Now I need to extract only CGX_CLAIMS (that is variable.. could be other string)... any idea?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `_W_` is static, you can use

```cs
_W_(.*?)_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFqj9p/1). *Details*:

- `_W_` - a known substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a line feed char, as few as possible
- `_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.` - `_`, four digits, `_`, two digits, `_`, two digits and a `.` char.

In C#, you can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Match(text, @"_W_(.*?)_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.")?.Groups[1].Value;
```